# filterContentForSearchText not displaying data on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I am trying to create a search bar that will update a UITableView with results from two data sources (local & API call). I am struggling to figure out the proper way to implement this.

I have a UITableView set up as a list of users with a search bar at the top.

[image]

When I have the code set to filter the UITableCells locally with the searchText it works perfectly.

[image]

However, when pulling data from Parse and trying to add that in the cells below the local search data nothing appears.

[image]

The code updates the `self.searchText` array properly but the data is never displayed in the tableView. What gives?

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    [self.searchResult removeAllObjects];
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];

    NSMutableArray *queryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query whereKey:@"fullName" hasPrefix:@"Joe"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        for (PFObject *pfObj in objects)
        {
            NSDictionary *person = [[NSDictionary alloc]
                                    initWithObjects:@[pfObj[@"fullName"], pfObj.objectId]
                                    forKeys:@[@"name", @"objectId"]];
            [queryArray addObject:person];
        }

        self.searchResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [self.contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];
        [self.searchResult addObjectsFromArray:queryArray];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}];    
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResult[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.contacts[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [self.searchResult count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [self.contacts count];
    }
}
```

Comment: have you implemented numberofrowsinsection ? post it here

Comment: You need to reload your tableView after you have finished loading the data from parse. Make sure you do this on the main queue

Comment: @pawan yes I have implemented numberOfRowsInSection. I have updated my post accordingly.

Comment: Where you are reloading tableview? after filtering content you should return on main thread & reload tableview.

Comment: @pawan I just updated the code to reload the table view and got it to work. I did not realize the tableView needed to be reloaded since the code worked for the local values previously without `[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData]`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are fetching the data from the server so that when it calls the method

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
```

it reloads the table with the current array `self.searchResult`, which has no values right now. So I think you should reload the search table after the data are retrieved from the server that is

```
if (!error) {
        for (PFObject *pfObj in objects)
        {
            NSDictionary *person = [[NSDictionary alloc]
                                    initWithObjects:@[pfObj[@"fullName"], pfObj.objectId]
                                    forKeys:@[@"name", @"objectId"]];
            [queryArray addObject:person];
        }

        self.searchResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [self.contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];
        [self.searchResult addObjectsFromArray:queryArray];
[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
```

And according to me, the best way would be to should show the local results first -- till the rest of the contacts load from Parse, that is.

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    [self.searchResult removeAllObjects];
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    self.searchResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [self.contacts    filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];

    NSMutableArray *queryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query whereKey:@"fullName" hasPrefix:@"Joe"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        for (PFObject *pfObj in objects)
        {
            NSDictionary *person = [[NSDictionary alloc]
                                    initWithObjects:@[pfObj[@"fullName"], pfObj.objectId]
                                    forKeys:@[@"name", @"objectId"]];
            [queryArray addObject:person];
        }
        [self.searchResult addObjectsFromArray:queryArray];
        self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}];    
}
```